# Tesseract распознавание картинки Java / Android

Tags: java, android, распознавание, распознавание-символов

Существует картинка:

```
String urlImage = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/....../blabla.jpg";
```

**Вопросы:** чем и как лучше преобразовать ее в Bitmap (использовать picasso, glide или что другое) ?

И какой минимальный код нужен для распознавания текста на этой картинке? Смотрю пока в сторону OCR Tesseract(под андроид tess-two). Или посоветуете что-нибудь другое? Распознавать нужно будет текст на русском.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы и так используете Firebase, возможно стоит посмотреть на ML Kit, русский поддерживает
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text#cloud-based

Answer (score 1):

glide 4.X.X

```
RequestListener listener=new RequestListener(){
@Override public boolean onResourceReady(...){
Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
return true;
}
};
Glide.with(this).asDrawable().load(urlImage).listener(listener).into(imageView);
```

//glide отличается от picasso только поддержкой Gif

Comment: этот код даст вам BitMap